# Must Declare Scalar variable on creating stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am creating first time stored procedure but I don't know why this showing error. I also have many other post but didn't understand if someone can tell what I am doing wrong here.

Stored procedure:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[DeleteOrganization]
    @ORG_ID bigint
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    delete from Organizations where ORG_ID=@ORGID
    delete from Institutes where INS_FK_ORGID=@ORGID
    delete from Branches where BRN_ID=@ORGID
END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable is declared as `@ORG_ID bigint` with an underscore but you refer to it without the underscore: `@ORGID`. Pick one and use it consistently.

This should work:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[DeleteOrganization]
@ORGID bigint
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;    
    DELETE FROM Organizations WHERE ORG_ID = @ORGID
    DELETE FROM Institutes WHERE INS_FK_ORGID = @ORGID
    DELETE FROM Branches WHERE BRN_ID = @ORGID
END
```

Comment: @Wajihurrehman Really? I tried executing your code and after changing the declaration to `@ORGID bigint` I had no problem running it.